# Prevent "Redirection loop detected" error in big data manipulation

Tags: php

I'm working on a script that should parse some data from different URLs. As script execution time is limited, script saves all URLs in session and then begin to walk around them. One - URL - one script execution. Then page refresh itself and continue to walk from the last URL. But there is one problem - browser do not like such redirections and aborts it. How can it be fixed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dump this meta data in response

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
```

to refresh page client side and avoid to reload server side.

Comment: Yeah, really, client-side redirections are not blocked by the browser. Thank you.